# Unable to change the priority with 'remove_action' and 'add_action' in child theme

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme

I am using an Woo theme. In the parent theme, there is this function:

```
function woothemes_wp_head() {
  do_action( 'woothemes_wp_head_before' );
  if ( function_exists( 'woo_output_alt_stylesheet' ) )
    woo_output_alt_stylesheet();
  if ( function_exists( 'woo_output_custom_favicon' ) )
    woo_output_custom_favicon();
  if ( function_exists( 'woo_head_css' ) )
    woo_head_css();
  if ( function_exists( 'woo_shortcode_stylesheet' ) )
    woo_shortcode_stylesheet();
  if ( function_exists( 'woo_output_custom_css' ) )
    woo_output_custom_css();
  do_action( 'woothemes_wp_head_after' );
}
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'woothemes_wp_head', 10 );
```

The above function basically adds different stylesheets inside `<head>`.

I am wanting to move the stylesheets up in the html markup. In my child theme's `functions.php`, this is what I tried:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'woothemes_wp_head', 10 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'woothemes_wp_head', 2 );
```

and

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'woothemes_wp_head');
add_action( 'wp_head', 'woothemes_wp_head', 2 );
```

Both these codes place the stylesheets up in the `<head>` but also retains the original ones; ie it makes 2 copies. `remove_action` doesn't seem to get rid of the original stylesheets.

I tried this code:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'woothemes_wp_head', 2);
function woothemes_wp_head() {
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'woothemes_wp_head', 10 );
}
```

This one completely removes the stylesheets.

So how do I simply change the priority?

Answer (score 1):

Your child theme `functions.php` loads *before* the parent theme's, so you're trying to remove the action before it's added by the parent theme.

Hook [`after_setup_theme`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme) to remove/add, which is executed after both child and parent load.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpd_wp_head_function' );
function wpd_wp_head_function() {
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'woothemes_wp_head', 10 );
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'woothemes_wp_head', 2 );
}
```

Comment: Yes, I realise why this was happening as you've explained. I tried your code but that's still adding duplicate stylesheets in html. So is there no other way to fix this behaviour from the child theme?

Comment: if there's duplicate, then again, you're not actually removing it, so there is something wrong in your code. edit your question to show exactly what you've got in your child theme now.

Comment: maybe another hook from main theme, like this https://github.com/rememberlenny/WooThemes-Canvas-Foundation-Zombie/blob/master/functions.php#L91 sometime OP not include all in context.